# Key Error while making Stacked Bar Graph in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, bokeh, keyerror

I am trying to make a stacked bar plot with bokeh.    I keep getting `KeyError: '1'` but can't figure out why. My pivot_table looks like this:

```
pivot_table.head(3)
Out[23]: 
Month                      1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
CompanyName                                                              
Company1   11   3   2   3   5   7   3   6   8   3   5   8
Company2   3   1   2  18   3   4   5   4   5   5   3   2
Company3   2   6   1   3   2   0   5   6   4   8   4   7
```

Here is my code:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.charts import Bar, output_file, show
import datetime as datetime


df = pd.read_csv('MYDATA.csv', usecols=[1, 16, 18]) #One is CompanyName, 16 is recvd_dttm, 18 is machinetype

# filter by countries with at least one medal and sort
df['recvd_dttm'] = pd.to_datetime(df['recvd_dttm'])

#Only retrieve data before now (ignore typos that are future dates)
mask = df['recvd_dttm'] <= datetime.datetime.now()
df = df.loc[mask]
# get first and last datetime for final week of data

range_max = df['recvd_dttm'].max()
range_min = range_max - datetime.timedelta(days=365)

# take slice with final week of data
df = df[(df['recvd_dttm'] >= range_min) & 
               (df['recvd_dttm'] <= range_max)]



df = df.set_index('recvd_dttm')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')

result = df.groupby([lambda idx: idx.month, 'CompanyName']).agg(len).reset_index()
result.columns = ['Month', 'CompanyName', 'NumberCalls']
pivot_table = result.pivot(index='Month', columns='CompanyName', values='NumberCalls').fillna(0)
s = pivot_table.sum().sort(ascending=False,inplace=False)
pivot_table = pivot_table.ix[:,s.index[:40]]
pivot_table = pivot_table.transpose()



pivot_table = pivot_table.reset_index()
pivot_table['CompanyName'] = [str(x) for x in pivot_table['CompanyName']]
Companies = list(pivot_table['CompanyName'])
months = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"]
pivot_table = pivot_table.set_index('CompanyName')
pivot_table.to_csv('pivot_table.csv')




# get the months
Jan = pivot_table['1'].astype(float).values
Feb = pivot_table['2'].astype(float).values
Mar = pivot_table['3'].astype(float).values
Apr = pivot_table['4'].astype(float).values
May = pivot_table['5'].astype(float).values
Jun = pivot_table['6'].astype(float).values
Jul = pivot_table['7'].astype(float).values
Aug = pivot_table['8'].astype(float).values
Sep = pivot_table['9'].astype(float).values
Oct = pivot_table['10'].astype(float).values
Nov = pivot_table['11'].astype(float).values
Dec = pivot_table['12'].astype(float).values
# build a dict containing the grouped data
months = OrderedDict(Jan=Jan, Feb=Feb, Mar=Mar, Apr=Apr, May=May,Jun=Jun,Jul=Jul,Aug=Aug,Sep=Sep,Oct=Oct,Nov=Nov,Dec=Dec)


# any of the following commented are also alid Bar inputs
#medals = pd.DataFrame(medals)
#medals = list(medals.values())

output_file("stacked_bar.html")

bar = Bar(months, Companies, title="Stacked bars", stacked=True)

show(bar)
```

I could make it fine in matplotlib, but I like the hovertool feature in bokeh. 
if I did `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and added these lines, I get a stacked bar plot.

```
plot = pivot_table.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)
show(plot)
```

I figure that the key error is coming from when I get the months for the OrderedDict? I don't know how to fix this. Basically I am trying to go off of this example: http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/stacked_bar_chart.html

Comment: You should be able to figure out from the stack trace (that massive load of text which appears when the error happens) where exactly the error is occurring. That would help to work out what's going on.

Comment: The KeyError '1' message suggests that your pivot table doesn't have a column with the label '1'. Do `print(pivot_table.columns)` to see what your column names actually are (if you have a multiindex columns).

Comment: @LondonRob I know that the error starts here: Jan = pivot_table['1'].astype(float).values when I try to call column '1' but I'm confused since that is definitely a column name.

Comment: @LukeCanavan 
 
 
Thanks for the hint. But when I put in pivot_table.columns it outputs pivot_table.columns Out[2]: Index([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], dtype='object') So... doesn't that mean that 1 is a column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though if I use `Jan = pivot_table[1].astype(float).values` instead of `Jan = pivot_table['1'].astype(float).values`, it works

Comment: That's probably it. Pandas must be parsing the input columns arg to ints.